# How to execute an order_by after using distinct?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-orm

I would like to sort my result after I have grabbed unique results based on two fields. The problem I'm having is that I cannot use two order_by in Django. [Django clears the previous `order_by()` whenever you use this function.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

> Each order_by() call will clear any previous ordering.

Example of models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.FloatField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to get the product which is in the same group and have the lowest. Then, I'd like to sort them by price. Something like this:

```
Product.objects.order_by('group','price').distinct('group').order_by('price')
Product.objects.order_by('group','price').distinct('group').order_by('-price')
```

The thing is that if just use in the first order by I get different products.

--

**EDIT**

Example of table:

```
id | name | group | price
0  | aaa  | aaa   | 10.0
1  | aaa  | aaa   | 1.0
2  | aaa  | aaa   | 2.0
3  | aaa  | aaa   | 1.0
4  | bbb  | bbb   | 2.0
5  | bbb  | bbb   | 2.1
6  | bbb  | bbb   | 10.0
```

Sorting by price:

```
1  | aaa  | aaa  | 1.0
4  | bbb  | bbb  | 2.0
```

Sorting by -price:

```
4  | bbb  | bbb  | 2.0
1  | aaa  | aaa  | 1.0
```

The problem I have is that when I sort using order_by the products returned are different.

In sql statement would be something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON 
  (group) id
  FROM product
  ORDER BY group ASC, price ASC
)
ORDER BY price DESC
```

I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: Actually, I couldn't quite get what you are trying to do here. Could you provide the sql query that you are trying to obtain?

Comment: Are you trying to get the lowest price per group, and have those sorted by price?

Comment: Isn't the ordering from the first `order_by` clause simply preserved if you chop off the second `order_by` clause?

Comment: @emre, I added the SQL query.

Comment: @SomeSillyName, exactly.

Comment: @voodoo-burguer, unfortunately not. I put the part of documentation which explains that.

Comment: @MarcusRenno I think you probably need to split this into two queries. Also look into `Aggregate()` and `Annotate()`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, here is what I did:

```
products = Product.objects.order_by('group','price').distinct('group')
result = Product.objects.filter(id__in=products).order_by('-price')
```

I don't think it's the most efficient way, but it is working...

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and found another solution. After the first request to DB with sorted_by followed by distinct you can:

```
import operator

products = Product.objects.order_by('group','price').distinct('group')
result = sorted(products, key=operator.attrgetter('price'), reverse=True)
```

This solution is better because you are not making the second request to the database.

Comment: This is a great and smart way to counter the Django ORM issue to sort values twice

Comment: If it's a small queryset, it's fine, but if it's large then sorting in memory is not the best way, because a. performance, and b. you can't do paging.

Answer (score 0):

I like Alexander's idea of using sorted.  I put the sorted function into a subclass of models.QuerySet and then set my ProductManager accordingly.  This allows you to chain the sorted method onto your queryset.

**Gotcha:** This returns a list rather than a queryset, so you cannot use any queryset methods after sorting.

**Related model field sort:**  You can sort by a related model field by passing a key that spans the lookup with dot operator (key='price.other')

```
manager.py
class ProductQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def sorted(self, key, reverse=False):
        """ Returns a list (rather than queryset) of Djano model instances """
        return sorted(self, key=operator.attrgetter(key), reverse=reverse)

    def current(self):
        return self.order_by('group', 'price').distinct('group')

class ProductManagerBase(models.Manager):
   pass

ProductManager = ProductManagerBase.from_queryset(ProductQuerySet)

models.py
...
objects = ProductManager()
```

**query

```
qs = (Product
     .current()
     .sorted('price', reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how I did it!
So I performed a subquery.**

*The inner query is running by the order by and distinct* based on the values that you need to be distinct **and the outer query is ordering your desired column**.

**Keep in mind, this is a sample code. Change it to what you need it to do. It worked for me and it might work for someone else.**

Sample Code:

```py
    from django.db.models import Subquery

    queryset = models.Products.objects.filter(
        pk__in=Subquery(
            models.Products.objects.filter(
               filter1=filter1,
               filter2=filter2,
               filter3=filter3
              ).order_by(
               'group'
              ).distinct(
              'group'
              ).values('pk')
           )
        ).order_by('-price')
```

Comment: Subquery is going to throw an error, in this sample... could you please include it's import?

Comment: @Shmack from django.db.models import Subquery